# Client-Side First Party and Third Party Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I understand that client-side first party cookies refer to cookies created on the page being browsed using `document.cookie`. However, I'm having trouble understanding client-side third party cookies. Is this conceptually possible but not practically, as when I try to specify a different domain using the `domain` parameter with `document.cookie`, the browser doesn't save the cookie? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Related: [When is a cookie considered to be a third party cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65668897) | [How do Third-Party "tracking cookies" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13897472) | [Regarding third-party cookies, who is a "second party"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71325236) | [How I can set third party cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12514222)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Third-party cookies can only be set by set-cookie HTTP response headers (or upon visits to the other site at which time they would be first-party cookies).

Client-side JS has no direct access to them, for reading or writing, via document.cookie or otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had this question for a long time and now it's much clearer!